# Django: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, collectstatic

I'm a beginner to django and trying to figure out how to incorporate ckeditor into a blog. I'm stuck at the step of copying ckeditor static files into the static root. No matter what fix I try, when I run python manage.py collectstatic, I get the error: ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

I've tried numerous online guides for ckeditor, read the django documentation on static files, and searched for an answer to this issue, but have not been able to find any answer which fixes the error.

Here is my current settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = ***

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        #My apps
        'blogger',
        'ckeditor',
        'ckeditor_uploader',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'blogs.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blogs.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ‘staticfiles’)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    )
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

I have read that since I am using the django development server, the collectstatic command may not work? I wasn't completely clear on that, but in that case, how would I go about copying ckeditor static files into the static root?

I am very new to programming and django, so I don't know if I am missing something, or not understanding something properly. If anyone has any ideas it would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you create the `staticfiles` directory?

Comment: Yes, in my app directory